# unknown status after calling localizedNetworkReachabilityStatusString

Tags: swift, alamofire

I need to send the status of the network to some analytics server, so I need to send it once the app starts. I tried to use Alamofire, but I usually get Unknown status, if there is some sort of delay it shows the right status :
These code would run in my AppDelegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().startMonitoring()
AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().localizedNetworkReachabilityStatusString()
```

What is the best way to get the right status right away?

UPDATE 1:

I updated my code and tried to use completion handler, but why when I use this method it will print multiple YES?

```
connectedCompletionBlock({ connected in

        if connected {
            print("YES")
        } else {
            print("NO")
        }

    })


class func connectedCompletionBlock(_ completion: @escaping (_ connected: Bool) -> Void) {

    AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().startMonitoring()

    AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().setReachabilityStatusChange({ status in

        var isConnected = false
        let wifi = AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.reachableViaWiFi
        let wwan =  AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.reachableViaWWAN

        if ( status == wifi || status == wwan)  {
            con = true
        }

        AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().stopMonitoring()
        completion(isConnected)


    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok since nobody didn't answer, I think it's good to share the solution with you. The issue was this: I was calling this method on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and since it takes sometime for the Alamofire to figure out the connection status it would return unknown! I called it on applicationDidBecomeActive and it works fine now.